# jQuery detect hover over left or right of a single div

Tags: jquery, hover, mouse

I have a photo gallery I am working on building, and I have a previous and next button that show and hide and change opacity depending on hover and such. Right now I have a wrapper around the image itself, then I have two divs inside at 50% width, left for previous, and right for next. I want to instead do this by detecting when you hover over the left or right 50% of the single div wrapper. The wrapper also has different possible widths, it uses 100% width to adjust to screen sizes.

I want it to replace:

```
$(".photo-previous, .photo-next").hover(function()
{
$(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
},
function()
{
$(this).fadeTo(100, 0.5);
}
);
```

Using mouse location instead of `.photo-previous` and `.photo-next`.

Comment: Your current implementation seems more elegant to me.

Comment: I agree, what's wrong with the current implementation?

Comment: I know this way is fine, and this is how I have always done it, though there have been two things that bother me about this, one - it covers the image so you cannot "save image" or "copy image location", etc. and two - jQuery's animations seem to be a bit slugging on these elements that have absolute positioning, I have read that they tend to do so. Perhaps that issue is unrelated though, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `mousemove` event.

```
$("#photoContainer").on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var mouseSide;
    if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2) {
        mouseSide = 'L';
    } else {
        mouseSide = 'R';
    }
});
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58Qdw/3/)

EDIT: Added `- this.offsetLeft` and updated fiddle.

Comment: upvoted, because my answer only addresses the initial rollover, and not moving the mouse around the container.

Answer (score 3):

I already said I liked your other implementation, but if you really want to do it a different way you can use the `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` members of your mouse event. So you could do something like...

```
$("#wrapper").mouseover(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offsetLeft;

    if(x < $(this).width() / 2)
        //left
    else
        //right
});
```

And that makes it dynamic so doesn't really matter what the width of the wrapper is.

I'm sure jquery UI's mouse plugin has some built in methods for getting relative mouse positions.

Answer (score -1):

There's a mouseover(function) that makes things like this easy.